# How to Populate the Auto Incremented values for the Instannce variable which are not annotated with @Id in Springboot application

Tags: java, hibernate

Here I would like to generate the Auto populated values for the "transactionNumber" variable and store it in the Database but I have used @Id on another the variable that is "accountNumber"

Note: I am using MYSQL Database

`Accounts`

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
public class Accounts {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "seq")
    private Integer accountNumber;
    
    /*
     * @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
     * 
     * @Target(ElementType.FIELD) public @interface InjectSequenceValue { String
     * sequencename(); }
     */
    
    /* @InjectSequenceValue(sequencename = "serialnum_sequence") */
    
    
    private int transactionNumber;
    
    @Column
    private String userId;
    
    @Column
    private int upiIdLimit;
    
    @Column
    private double accountBalance;
    
    @Column
    private String transactionLimitPerDay;
    
    
    public Integer getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(Integer accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    public int getTransactionNumber() {
        return transactionNumber;
    }

    public void setTransactionNumber(int transactionNumber) {
        this.transactionNumber = transactionNumber;
    }

    public String  getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public int getUpiIdLimit() {
        return upiIdLimit;
    }

    public void setUpiIdLimit(int upiIdLimit) {
        this.upiIdLimit = upiIdLimit;
    }

    public double getAccountBalance() {
        return accountBalance;
    }

    public void setAccountBalance(double accountBalance) {
        this.accountBalance = accountBalance;
    }

    public String getTransactionLimitPerDay() {
        return transactionLimitPerDay;
    }

    public void setTransactionLimitPerDay(String transactionLimitPerDay) {
        this.transactionLimitPerDay = transactionLimitPerDay;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: you want `transactionNumber` to be populated with the values that is the same as  `accountNumber` once it is assigned with `accountNumber` ?

Comment: Hi @Ken Chan if same is also no problem but Autogeneration of the  transactionNo is required for me and it should be stored in the Database.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL the table structure cannot contain more than one auto_increment field. When you try to create a table with 2 autoincremented fields or alter the table in an attempt to create a second autoincrement, the query fails.

### Options:

1. Create two tables with two different primary keys. Then you will be able to increment both column values.
2. Create a Database trigger ( [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual: 25.3.1 Trigger Syntax and Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) ):

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER 'INCREMENT_AccountNumber' AFTER INSERT ON 'Accounts' FOR EACH ROW BEGIN UPDATE class SET AccountNumber = AccountNumber+1 WHERE ID= ID; END
   ```
3. You can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary column in a multiple-column index for MyISAM(MyISAM is optimized for environments with heavy read operations, and few writes, or none at all).
   [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual: 3.6.9 Using AUTO_INCREMENT - MyISAM Notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html#:%7E:text=For%20MyISAM%20tables%2C%20you%20can,put%20data%20into%20ordered%20groups.)

Comment: Hi Dmitrii Podlesnykh is there another way as this will Impact on Performance ?